# How to Sort Data by checkbox selection in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

If I have an array `var item[];` and populate it with data:

```
var item = {title: displayTitle, DateDecription: dateDisplay, Date: new Date(eventDate), Region: region,}
                    data.push(item);
```

How can I sort this data by checkbox selection? for example `Region` may be "ALL","SF","SCV",or "OEB" if I have a checkbox for each of these possible regions how can I sort it by selection? By if statement? for each loop? Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: need to see some html. Also, do you mean sort or filter? A demo would help and better explanation of what you want to do with the data

Comment: This is a close as I could get it: http://jsfiddle.net/pU3gz/